# Is it possible to create macro buttons to navigate in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a database in Google Sheets per the link below:

[Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16tq-m2jhvxoi6sL8A0C_Fkx6BoNeaeFZzNQTM_zc06A/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to add buttons like you can in excel where you can record a macro to navigate or open another sheet or perform a particular function. For example in my database, I could create a home page with buttons to open certain sheets. I could then hide all of the sheets and only have a home page.

Or, perhaps hide the query data in cell C2 in the 'Other Attendances' sheet and create a button to open up the query.

Is any of this possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Yes.  This is possible.

Comment: @Cooper - fantastic, are you able to direct me to some instruction?

Comment: You are looking for "insert function button" and "change active sheet"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's create a button to go to the left hand most page.  Please select one of the right hand pages or push the + sign in the lower left to create one.

Here's the script:

```
function gotoMostLeftPage() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

Now we need a button:

[image]

We can use insert/Drawing to draw an image of our drawing.

[image]

In this case I'm using a basic shape.  You can add text if you like.

[image]

Now just save and close.

[image]

Drag the button to where you want it and click on the three buttons in the upper right.
Select Assign script.

[image]

Copy the script name.

[image]

Paste it into the dialog and click ok.

Try clicking on the button and it should take you to the left most page unless you are already there.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't realise that you could do that in Google Sheets

Comment: You can also create your own menus and put links to your own functions thus negating the need to create button images.  You can also put buttons on a sidebar with html and they can call your own functions on the server with google.script.run you can learn more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)