# How do i link a script app in drive to my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which I have created in Google drive as I want it to be a standalone script to that of the spreadsheet - mainly because other users have been fidling with the scripts and the sheet didn't function properly until i found all the problems!!

One of the scripts is this:

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
var ASCENDING = true;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 2;

var activeSheet;

function autoSort(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}

function onClickButton() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(sheet);
}
```

I have found this online which apparently links the app script to the spreadsheet but this doesn't work for me... `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.OpenFileById(xxx__xxx)`

- `(xxx__xxx)` being the spreadsheet id taken as: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**xxx__xxx**/edit#gid=1611726502

This just returns the following when I run the script:
`TypeError: Cannot find function OpenFileById in object.`

Please could someone assist on where i either put the code `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.OpenFileById(xxx__xxx)` within the script or the best script to use find the spreadsheet based on the sheet ID?

p.s. i will need to run the function `onClickButton` if that makes any difference...

Comment: This looks like a container bound script.  So if you want to run a function from a button click you will have to create a webapp so that you can create the button with html.  This is definitely not the easiest way to learn Google Apps Script.

Comment: You can access any Spreadsheet that you have access to with `SpreadsheetApp.openById();` from a Standalone Script.  Note: this does not actually open up the spreadsheet in the same manner as a user opening up a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting a Spreadsheet from a Standalone Script**

```
var ssid="Spreadsheet Id";

function sortingSS() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  rg.sort({column:1,ascending:true});
}
```

Sheet before sort

[image]

Sheet after sort

[image]

**Adding it to a menu**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Project Menu")
  .addItem("Sorting Spreadsheet", "sortingSS")
  .addToUi();
}
```

**[Creating a button of your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532556/7215091)**

Comment: Thanks @Cooper - that seems to work in autosorting the sheet.  Please can you confirm how i customize this: ```var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());```
I really want to sort the sheet by column '2 (A)' rather than '1 (B)' and the sheet has two header rows, how do I add this into the code?

So far so good though.....

Comment: Column A is column 1 Column B is column 2 `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`

Comment: Thanks @cooper that script works well, do you know how I could assign that to a button?  Or is there another way I can run that script manually from the spreadsheet itself?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532556/7215091)

Comment: Thanks @Cooper - how would I assign the sortingSS function to a button, I have previously used a button like
```function onClickButton() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(sheet);
}```
when the button is using code written in the sheets script editor.
As this is a script on Drive, how would I assign that ```sortingSS``` function please to the button?