# Read a standalone Google Apps Script in a specific spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have a script that I am running in an Apps Script created from Google Drive as follows:

```
var ssid="14ESdH--------------------------------HOn8A";

SHEET_NAME = "Chilled Sheet";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:F";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 2, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function autoSort(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

When I run this script in the apps script the function works as it should.  I would now like to run this function from a button within the sheet.  Previously I have written a script that is like the below within the script situated within the spreadsheet itself:

```
function onClickButton() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(sheet);
}
```

Unfortunately, using this and editing it several times various ways I can't get the button on my sheet to read script `onClickButton`.  I deleted this out eventually and tried running the script `autoSort` with the button which also didint work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can run the sheet with a button that activates the `autoSort` script please?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532556/7215091) you can following to create and connect a button to a script.

Now with reference to this script:

```
function onClickButton() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(sheet);
}
```

You should note that you are including the parameter 'sheet'

But in this function definition there is no parameter.

```
function autoSort(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

Personally I would always include all the values needed for the function to run within the function definition.

```
var ssid="14ESdH--------------------------------HOn8A";
SHEET_NAME = "Chilled Sheet";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:F";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 2, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order];
```

Perhaps you didn't notice that in the line  immediately above the comment is placed inside of the string for SORT_ORDER so that's not going to work.

```
function autoSort(){
  var SHEET_NAME = "Chilled Sheet";
  var SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:F";
  var SORT_ORDER = [{column: 2, ascending: true}];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

and since they're hard wired any way I would just do it like this:

```
function autoSort(){
  var ssid="14ESdH--------------------------------HOn8A";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Chilled Sheet");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:F");
  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cooper - when I assign that script to a button using ```autoSort``` then click on the button the following message comes up:
There was a problem
Script function autoSort could not be found

Any ideas??

I'm wondering if I need an additional script in the spreadsheet that reads the script and assigns it through the onClickButton script?

Comment: @Gav That error comes up when the function `autoSort` is not declared in the global scope (that means, not declared outside of any other function). Please copy the `autoSort()` code provided in Cooper's answer into your editor & kindly try again. Cheers

Comment: I have copied the code and assigned the autoSort() function to the button but still get the same error message.

Comment: Do you have more than one autoSort() function?