# Why isn't the function submitData adding the fields to the specified sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am totally new at this. I saw a script for data input without forms. I followed the script suggested elsewhere but it's not updating the values in the specified sheet. Can formatting in the datasheet be the problem? should i attach the file?

```
    function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("New Data"); //Data Entry Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Business Info"); //Business Info Data Sheet

  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("B3").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B14").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B15").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B16").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B17").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B18").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B19").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B20").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B21").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B23").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B24").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B25").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B26").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B27").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B28").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B29").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B30").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B31").getValue(),]];

  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 27).setValues(values);

}

function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("New Data");
  var rangesToClear = ["B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10","B11","B13","B14","B15","B16","B17","B18","B19","B20","B21","B23","B24","B25","B26","B27","B28","B29","B30","B31"];            
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.setActiveSelection(e.range.offset(1, 0));
}
```

Comment: Have you installed a script trigger to run the script?

Comment: Yes, and it runs without errors or so the popup says. There is just no data added to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function submitData() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const fsh=ss.getSheetByName("New Data");
  const frg=fsh.getRange(1,2,31,1);
  const vs=frg.getValues();
  const dsh=ss.getSheetByName("Business Info");
  const out=new Set([1,2,12,22]); 
  let values=vs.map(function(r,i){if(!out.has(i+1))return r;}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,27).setValues(values);
  //clear1();
}

function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("New Data");
  var rangesToClear = ["B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10","B11","B13","B14","B15","B16","B17","B18","B19","B20","B21","B23","B24","B25","B26","B27","B28","B29","B30","B31"];            
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="New Data")return; 
  e.source.setActiveSelection(e.range.offset(1, 0));
}//I'm guessing your doing this to get the cursor to move down after every entry but you will have problems on rows 12 and 22
```

And then you can create and install a submit button as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532556/7215091).  I'm assuming that you want to run the submitData() function when you click the button and possibly add the command to call clear1 at the end of submitData().  You could also use the sidebar to create html buttons which can do the same thing but they use google.script.run to call any function on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the range of each cell. You can just specify a multi-cell range and use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()). This will return a 2D array, which you can convert to a 1D array with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). This last method is used in the sample below:

```js
function submitData() {
  const ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("New Data");
  const datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Business Info");
  const values = formSS.getRange("B3:B31").getValues().flat();
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
}
```

By using `values.length`, you can make your destination range have a dynamic number of columns, depending on the input range.

You can also greatly simplify your function `clear1` by doing this:

```js
function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("New Data");
  var rangeToClear = "B3:B31";
  sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clearContent();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())